# How to download larger size SharePoint files using C# Web Client

Tags: c#

I am trying to download files from SharePoint using C# Web Client. I could able to download the file but not the full file. SharePoint file size: 7MB but downloaded file through program is just 86KB. Not sure what's the issue!!

-- Used Web client to download file.

```cs
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    client.Headers.Add("X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED", "f");
    client.Headers.Add("User-Agent: Other");
    client.Credentials = credentials;
    client.DownloadFile(webUrl, downloadPath);
    //client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(webUrl), fileRelativeUrl);

    client.Dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually when a downloaded file is much smaller (eg. few KB to a few hundred KB) it means that you downloaded HTML code.

Rename the resulting downloadPath file to something.html and open it in your browser, you will most likely see an error message from sharepoint that will point you to the underlying error (eg. unauthorized, file not found or something else).

Comment: Hi, I want to download XLSX file. So how can I download full file?? I don’t want to be in HTML format.

Comment: the html is the reply from sharepoint of the error that you have. read the html, solve the error then you get the xlsx file.

Comment: When i open the html, it's blank. There is no error.

Comment: Well, you said it's 86KB so it has to contain something. At least 86KB of content.